# R/Lubridate is reading my Date-Time wrong

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Source .csv file is here: https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html (Just Jul 2021 will do as an example month.

My eventual goal is to get the difftime between started_at and ended_at , and assign a calendar-day of the week to each date.

But i've been at it for hours, and i cant get R to read the date correctly... i can tell it's this because when i try splitting the date up into different components using the following code, i get it in a weird order

```
library(tidyverse)
Total_trips <- read_csv("1_202107.csv")
Total_trips $ date <- as.Date(Total_trips $ started_at)
Total_trips $ day <- format(as.Date(Total_trips $ date),'%d')
Total_trips $ month <- format(as.Date(Total_trips $ date),'%m')
Total_trips $ year <- format(as.Date(Total_trips $ date),'%Y')
Total_trips $ day_of_week <- format(as.Date(Total_trips $ date),'%A')
```

02/07/2021 14:44 becomes: 2-07-20 Saturday .... with 20 as the day, 07 as the month, 2 as the year

Could someone help me out please? Thanks <3

Comment: Hi. I'm trying on the first file you provided and many days don't have any difference between them. What is the purpose of having the day of the week? Could you provide a clean line for what you would expect back please?

Comment: Hey, overall, im trying to analyse the difference in use between members, and casual users at this bike hire company. One hypothesis is that casual users may use more on weekends, or on holidays, so the day of the week might be useful. Another possible insight is how much time casual members ride for. Also, what did you mean by "many days dont have any difference between them"? thanks

Comment: Yes, but for instance if this was your row for start and end date, what are you expecting the result to look like?: 2020-04-12 12:40:08 2020-04-12 12:59:32

Comment: apologies sent my last reply too early. I unfortunately also don't know what you mean by "line"

Comment: Basically just want it to come back as: 02(day), 07(month), 2021(year). Ideally, i just want to leave the whole thing intact, so difftime can calculate correctly in instances where end_date is different to start_date

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how to extract the date from your columns and calculate the difference between the two. The lubridate preferred format is always ymd, thus in this case because the dates are already in that format you don't actually need to move anything. You can use the date function from lubridate to extract the date component, then use difftime to calculate the time difference.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = read.csv("202004-divvy-tripdata.csv")

df = df %>% 
  select(started_at,ended_at) %>% 
  mutate(started_at = date(started_at)) %>% 
  mutate(ended_at = date(ended_at)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = difftime(started_at,ended_at, units = "mins"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood if you then need to paste the day onto the dates for some reason. Should you need to do this you can use the function weekdays() from base R and paste it onto the date. mutate(paste(started_at,weekdays(stared_at))).

Comment: Heyy, i'm still running into the same problem. I'm using the month of July 2021, and the year is still coming back as "20", instead of "21". I think there may be an issue with the .csv file of this month - as it is working on the file that you referenced. - Furthermore, i need to find the difftime in mins (e.g. did user ride for 30minutes on Monday, and 4hours on Saturday?)

Comment: I've changed units, it now returns minutes. Also, the raw .csv file has the same dates as when it is brought in R. Thus I suggest if you're expecting to see 2021 dates it's an issue with your raw data.